# my terminal is only printing the first output from main

Tags: c

beginner to C here, and I am having trouble printing the words "one" in int one_three() and "two" in in the function().

the only words printing in my terminal is "starting now" - is anyone anyone aware as to why this is happening?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
int one_three();
int two();

int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    int one_three();
    int two();

    return 0;
}

int one_three()
{
    printf("one");
    int two();

    return 0;
}

int two()
{
    printf("two");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to learn C grammar before writing code.

Comment: thank you, on to it now!

Comment: Go through the C syntax first and be clear about it. The reason your code isn't getting you the desired output is because you have declared the function twice once at the head of your file and second at the end of main() block. Next you went ahead to define the function. So you see what is missing here? You have declared the function, you have defined the function but nowhere have you called that function. To call a function simply write it's name followed by parentheses and semi-colon but not preceded by any data type/access modifier etc. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You don't *call* the functions, you *declare* the functions (again).

To call e.g. `one_three` then you do

```
one_three();
```

---

And speaking about function declarations, in C you must explicitly use `void` as argument if a function doesn't take any arguments. A declaration such as

```
int two();
```

tells the compiler that the function `two` returns an `int`, and takes an unknown number of unspecified arguments. The proper declaration would be

```
int two(void);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int one_three();
int two();

int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    one_three();
    two();

    return 0;
}

int one_three()
{
    printf("one");
    two();

    return 0;
}

int two()
{
    printf("two");

    return 0;
}
```

While calling the function you should not declare the type(ie. char, int or float).

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code like this.

```
...
int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    one_three();
    two();

    return 0;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared functions again inside `main()`. That's why printing only **"starting now"**. You need to call that function from `main()` like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    one_three();
    two();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you some basics.
The first two lines in your code

```
int one_three();
int two();
```

- are function declarations or function prototypes which tells the compiler that there is a function definition after the main function.

If you don't want it, you can keep the function definitions before main function.

```
int one_three()
{
    printf("one");
    int two();

    return 0;
}

int two()
{
    printf("two");

    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    one_three(void);
    two(void);

    return 0;
}
```

You're re-declaring the functions again in main(), where you need to call them.
Pass a actual argument as **void** if you're not passing any value or reference.
Since you're returning 0 from those functions the return type is int, which will be fine.

```
int main(void)
{
    // Countdown begins
    printf("starting now: ");
    printf("\n");
    one_three(void);
    two(void);

    return 0;
}
```